# Laravel Validator exists or equal to / conditonal or

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

I have an input value that can be either an actual ID existing in the database or a 0 indicating special case.

In any case, if this value is sent not-empty, I need it to be validated with something like

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'item_id.*' => 'required|in:0[OR]exists:items_table,id',
]);
```

The problem is I did not manage to find any documentation on how to do this **"`[OR]`"**. Almost everything I managed to find is related to testing against other key or checking *just* against an explicit array without the exists "or".

**NOTE:** This is **not** case of ***required_if/unless*** because I need to check against the currently tested value, not against other key.

**NOTE2:** This page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation does not provide the answer

Comment: You'll need a custom validator for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write your own validation rules for that variable. Something like this:

```
if (!empty($data->item_id)){
    if($data->item_id<>0 || $data->item_id <not in list of values>){
          return Redirect::back()->withErrors('error messages here')->withInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid non-laravel code for better maintainability, of course I can do the validation by myself in pure PHP :)

Comment: I definitely understand the allure of using the Laravel framework; it often seems like the most elegant solution and the "right" way to do it. But sometimes it's just faster to do it with pure PHP. :-)
As far as maintainability goes, pure PHP is more stable and less likely to change syntax quickly, whereas you may have to update the Validator:: syntax often as you upgrade Laravel.

Comment: it's only faster for the initial creation moment, by maintainability I meant code passing to future editors, future quick passing gets slow when you start to mingle 2 approaches. So ain't nobody talking about the "right" way, but the "Laravel" way on purpose :) However I agree with your point, just not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility for don't create a new validator is create an array before check.
This is not the best way, but work.
For exemple:

```
public function rules() {
    // here you create an array with all data
    $items = ItemsTabe::select('id')->pluck('id')->toArray();
    $allItems = '0,' . implode(',', $items);
    $allItems = explode(',', $allItems);
    return [
        'item_id' => [
            'required',
        ],
        'item_id.*' => [
            Rule::in($allItems),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Comment: Good thought, but your first 3 lines are a bit of a mess. How about `$allItems = Items::pluck('id'); $allItems[] = 0;`